# A time registration with knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create an extremely dynamic table (adding, removing lines, making certain cells clickable to inject meaningful information, making subselects in which shift a certain registration had been made, ...).

At the moment I'm creating this with pure jQuery but I notice that I'm already writing a lot of functions and workaround, in combination with *underscore.js*, to get it working.

A very simplified version can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/KvdM/FxmbB/9/.

I took the online tutorials from http://learn.knockoutjs.com/. I'm wondering if I can make a way cleaner and more maintainable solution with knockout.js and templates.

The json that serves as input and which needs to keep in sync with what was put into the table now comes from ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may answer your question. IMHO, knockout is a much more maintainable solution.
 http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/eY9w8/7/

Comment: That looks like in the right direction. How can a footer be added which shows the sum of the columns?